# how to connect to a remote server through R?

Tags: mysql, r, sqlite, rsqlite

I'm trying to connect to the server through the SQLite package but can't find the right spelling of database credentials anywhere. Actually I have MySQL and PostgreSQL bases on the server and I found a way to connect to a PostgreSQL it sounds like this:

```
drv <- dbDriver('PostgreSQL')
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname='...', user='...',
password='...', host='...', port=...)
```

but if I change the driver to ('SQLite') and the database credentials, it shows me:

```
Error in sqliteNewConnection(drv, ...) :
unused arguments (user = ......blablabla
```

Does anybody knows what the right arguments for MySQL database connection are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing things up here. You'll need `RMySQL` to connect to a `MySQL` database. [`MySQL` is Oracle's](http://www.mysql.com/) light (and free) version  of a relational DBMS. [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is something different. That being said, if you got the choice, go with `PostgreSQL` if it's meant to stay, otherwise `SQLite` might be ok for some testing. R and `PostgreSQL` really work well together.

Ah, and note that there was NO windows binary of `RMySQL` on CRAN when I wrote this. 
SO if you are on Windows and want to use R with MySQL you gotta compile the package. 
With the right R setup it should just be a matter of `install.packages('RMySQL',type='source')`.

If you are not ready to compile on your own `RODBC` might also work for you.

Comment: Ok, so what you need is two packages one for each database: e.g. `RMySQL` and `SQLite` unless you use ODBC. w.r.t the compilation issue, what happens if you just run the install.packages line i dropped above?

Comment: thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I have two differently structured data bases as is, so I can't choose) 
I tried to compile the package but after I extract the source from the .gz I've got an error
`ERROR: configuration failed for package 'RMySQL'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/RMySQL'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/bi...`

Comment: I also tried to check this address
`Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/.../.../AppData/Local/Temp/.../downloaded_packages/RMySQL_0.9-3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status`
the archive is lying there, but when I trying to extract the source from that archive it shows the the exact error I mentioned above

Comment: If you really added the `type="source" parameter`, you probably don't have the right compiler installed. Rtools.exe (google for that). may help on windows, but if you have no idea you might just want to try 'RODBC' and connect to your databases by using ODBC.

Comment: Hmm, there are lots of tutorials around on how to build packages on windows. Rob Hyndman is really good and also explains things well: http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/building-r-packages-for-windows/

Comment: I have no experience with packages creation, and nobody can show me how to do it unfortunately (( I tried to connect with RODBC with such a command:
`odbcDriverConnect(connection='driver={SQL Server};uid=****;pwd=****;server=****;database=thetribez;Port=3308;trusted_connection=true')`
and it shows me a long-long error message:

Comment: `Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "driver={SQL Server};uid=gstat;pwd=e48y0Ypbg;server=analytics.bt44.my.ru;database=thetribez;Port=3308;trusted_connection=true") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 17, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server не существует, или доступ запрещен.` wich means Server is not exist or access denied, but I can connect to it through the Navicat with exact credentials

Comment: found the problem I had to have the MySQL Connector which I installed, wrote through the credentials and now I can write RODBC queries )